# Oracle SQL - Combine Two Results from Two Queries Into One

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these two separate queries:

Query 1

```
select '2013-03-03' As "Week_Of",
count(player_id) as cohort_size
from player
where trunc(create_dtime) > To_Date('2013-Mar-03','yyyy-mon-dd')-7
and trunc(create_dtime) <= To_Date('2013-Mar-03','yyyy-mon-dd')
and world_flag != '1'
;
```

Which outputs:

```
Week_of      Cohort_size
2013-03-03      18183
```

Query 2

```
select '2013-03-03' As "Week_Of", 
count(player_id) as Day_0_Ret
from player
where trunc(init_dtime)-trunc(create_dtime) >= 0
and trunc(create_dtime) > To_Date('2013-Mar-03','yyyy-mon-dd')-7
and trunc(create_dtime) <= To_Date('2013-Mar-03','yyyy-mon-dd')
and world_flag != '1'
;
```

Which Outputs:

```
Week_of      Day_0_Ret
2013-03-03      15684
```

I want to bring these two queries together so I have one query that outputs:

```
Week_of         Cohort_Size     Day_0_Ret
2013-03-03       18183              15684
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `case` statement to do a conditional count:

```
select '2013-03-03' As "Week_Of",
count(player_id) as cohort_size ,
count(case 
        when trunc(init_dtime)-trunc(create_dtime) >= 0 
        then player_id 
      end) as Day_0_Ret
from player
where trunc(create_dtime) > To_Date('2013-Mar-03','yyyy-mon-dd')-7
and trunc(create_dtime) <= To_Date('2013-Mar-03','yyyy-mon-dd')
and world_flag != '1'
;
```